# Odoo line break in field name

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I try to use a line break in a field name because the insert field is way to small caused by a long field name... i tried `<![CDATA[&#xD;]]> and <![CDATA[&#xA;]]>` and also \n in the field string at the python file but nothing worked.

This is the part i'm trying to change, where wordnumbertwo should be line breaked.

```
<attribute name="string">Wordnumberone/ wordnumbertwo</attribute>
```

Any suggestions how to get the line break done?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i solved it like this:

For the specific field which is triggered by the `expr="pathtofield"`, the old css class `oe_form_label` gets replaced by `oe_form_label_new`.

```xml
<xpath expr="pathtofield" position="attributes">
    <attribute name="class">oe_form_label oe_form_label_new</attribute>
</xpath>
```

The css class to line break my field:

```
.oe_form_label_new {white-space: normal !important;}
```

Comment: Hi Manu, thank you for your solution. Im trying to do that via your solution.But Im stuck in expr="pathtofield". Can you please to explain more. Thank you!